# Python unicode normalization issue

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8, codec

I am trying to convert a file that contains some unicode characters in it and replace it with normal characters. I am facing some problem with that and get the following error.

```
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode bytes in position 1-3: invalid data
```

My file looks like below:

```
ecteDV
ecteBl
agnéto
```

the code to replace accents is shown below:

```
 #!/usr/bin/python
 # -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

 import re, sys, unicodedata, codecs

 f = codecs.open(sys.argv[1], 'r', 'utf-8')
 for line in f:
     name = line.lower().strip()
     normal = unicodedata.normalize('NFKD', name).encode('ASCII', 'ignore')
     print normal
 f.close()
```

Is there a way I can replace all the accents and normalize the contents of the file?

Comment: Your input file is broken; it has invalid UTF-8 data in it. Are you 100% certain that it **is** UTF-8 data?

Comment: You are also not *calling* the `f.close` function; you'd use `f.close()` normally, or use `f` as a context manager.

Comment: Does 'é' not the part of utf-8?

Comment: UTF-8 is an **encoding**; it can encode `é`, but so can the ISO-8859 Latin 1 encoding. So can many other codecs.

Comment: the thing I want to do is that I have a file that have accents like  'é' and I want them to be replace by normal characters. I can do that by using ordinary re.sub() function but I wanted to use the unicodedate.

Comment: I fully understand what you are trying to do, but it is clear you don't understand what codecs are. I suggest you go read http://www.joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html first, followed by http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html and http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html before continuing.

Comment: Alright! I will have a look the links before contiuing. Thanks Martijn.

Comment: I have looked into it and realized that the file was in ISO-8859-1 encoding and I was using utf-8.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider that your file is perhaps **not** using UTF-8 as the encoding.

You are reading the file with the UTF-8 codec but decoding fails. Check that your file encoding is *really* UTF-8.

Note that UTF-8 is an encoding out of many, it doesn't mean 'decode magically to Unicode'.

If you don't yet understand what encodings are (as opposed to what Unicode is, a related but separate concept), you need to do some reading:

- [The Absolute Minimum Every Software Developer Absolutely, Positively Must Know About Unicode and Character Sets (No Excuses!)](http://joelonsoftware.com/articles/Unicode.html) by Joel Spolsky
- The [Python Unicode HOWTO](http://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)
- [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html) by Ned Batchelder

Answer (score -2):

Try opening the file with the following code and replace sys.argv[1] with the filename.

```
import re, sys, unicodedata, codecs

with codecs.open("filename", 'r', 'utf-8') as f:
    for line in f:
        do something 

 f.close()
```

Comment: How is that going to fix the error **in the file data**?

Comment: If you want to find the error in the file by first opening it then you use codecs to recognize non - ASCII characters, then you can loop in the lines in the file and find the error. To me it seems you're trying to strip your code and open it so it recognizes non - ASCII so it seems more to me that the issue is the opening of the file and not the file content itself.

Comment: You are not talking to the OP here, I didn't post this question. The OP has not included a traceback, but it will **not** be the filename that caused the decoding error, because the filename from `sys.argv[1]` is not being decoded. But the file *contents* **are** being decoded.

Comment: From my conversation in the comments it appears that the OP is confused about what UTF-8 **is**; I suspect the term is being confused with Unicode. The file is probably not encoded in UTF-8, but some other codec.

Comment: That's the purpose of using codecs when opening a file. The above code works for opening with utf-8 so that non - ASCII characters such as "é" are decoded/recognized. Pardon for adressing you as the OP, but same reply as above.